# Angular 5 authentication security without angularfireauth routing doesn't work

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular5, angularfire

I have an Angular 5 app with an admin panel which will only have one user that can get the data from my firebase db, due to the hosting service of the website I don't use a real backend and use firebase as a NOSQL db. I tried okta but couldn't get it to work so I'm looking for other options. I redirect my route so only logged in users can get to the admin-overview component but my way of checking the users login credentials is bad and I'm looking for an easy and better way. I only need one user. What are my options?

admin-component

```
loginUser() {
  if(this.username == 'test' && this.password == 'test'){
    this.service.login().subscribe(userIsLoggedIn =>
      this.router.navigate(['admin/overview']));
  }
}
```

routing

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  component: AdminLoginComponent,
  data: {title: 'Admin'}
},
{
  path: 'admin/overview',
  component: AdminOverviewComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  data: {title: 'Overview'}
}
```

Comment: No related but accessing DOM like... `e.target.elements[0].value;` is not really angularish. We have a perfectly usable `[(ngModel)]` for this usecase ;)

Comment: So  `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">` is inside a `<form>` and it gave some errors don't remember which but what would be the appropriate way?

Comment: Maybe first read https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax and then is a forms section in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/forms But yes, this is has nothing to do with your question, but definitely worth reading if you are going to work with Angular.

Comment: Had to name the input in html now it's how it's supposed to be, I'm reading up on firebase too maybe there's a way to authenticate a single user with firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the simple authentication working with AngularFireAuth

auth-service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth){
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
  }
  isLoggedIn = false;

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    this.firebaseAuth
  .auth
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(value => {
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
    return Observable.of(true).delay(1000).do(val => this.isLoggedIn = true);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
  });
return Observable.of(false).delay(1000).do(val => this.isLoggedIn = false);
}
}
```

login component

```
constructor(private router: Router, private service: AuthService){}
loginUser() {
    this.service.login(this.email, this.password).subscribe(userIsLoggedIn =>
      this.router.navigate(['admin/overview']));
      this.email = this.password = '';
      console.log('test');
  }
```